# Convert Base64 String to Image (which sent from android using JSON) and save as BLOB in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, base64

Actually I had get the image string from the JSON in my android project. The string image successfully pass to using HTTPPOST. 
Now, I face the problem on saving an image as blob type in mysql database in php.
How to convert the string image i get so that it can be save as a blob type in mysql database?
If anyone know the way please kindly advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) the data:

```
$blob = base64_decode($json_64_encoded_string);
```

Then write it to the DB. If you need help getting the encoded string out of the `POST` array have a look at the PHP `json_decode` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json_obj = json_decode($_POST[post_key]); //replace 'post_key' with whatever you use
$blob = base64_decode($json_obj->blob); //replace 'blob' with whatever you use
```